# WooCommerce: change link in email send to customer

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using Tutor LMS and WooCommerce. When a student orders an online course, the student will receive an email with details about the order. In this case, there is a link to the WooCommerce product page listing the video course (because tutor LMS requires to create a product in WooCommerce in order to create a video course). But I want to change this link in the send email so the student goes directly to the Tutor LMS dashboard / Enrollment page instead of the WooCommerce product page.

[image: ,]

I can't figure out how to change this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, Tutor LMS stores `_tutor_course_product_id` meta values for LMS products. The link you see in your e-mails should be filtered with `woocommerce_order_item_permalink` filter.

This means you could utilize this filter, check if that LMS specific meta key exists for that product and if so, set the link to your custom dashboard URL, instead of native product permalink.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', 'tutor_lms_order_item_permalink', 20, 2 );
function tutor_lms_order_item_permalink( $product_permalink, $item ) {

    // Attempt to get Tutor LMS course ID from this product
    $course_id = get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_tutor_course_product_id', true );
    if( $course_id ) {

        // Return LMS page dashboard URL instead of product permalink
        $product_permalink = 'your_url';
    }

    return $product_permalink;
}
```